# iPhone 6 can't find network

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 6 and it has the following problem:

- the phone can find my sim card, but can't find any network. It does everything, including finding Wifi- and Bluetooth-connections.

When I put off the location services after a hard reset, the iPhone can't find the correct time and date. When I take my sim card out and put it in another smartphone, the time and date on this phone is messed up too.

Only after I put on the location services and the Wifi, the phone is able to find the right time and date.

For info: Here in Belgium, we only have unlocked SIM cards, so it is nothing like that. The SIM card works fine in other smartphones, except for the time and date being out of order.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities.

1. Broken SIM card. This would be more likely because SIM cards are small and break easily. However, you mentioned that the SIM card works ok in other phones. I would still suggest getting a replacement SIM card, as that will be easier than the other possibility.
2. Problematic phone. It is possible that the problem is with the phone itself. It could be a hardware problem, a firmware problem, or a software problem. The only way to tell would be to take the phone to an Apple Store (or, if that's not possible, an Apple Authorized Service Provider) to get it checked out.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the SIM card is kind of broken. Contact the carrier to get a replacement.

Comment: I doubt it. The question states that the SIM card works in other phones.

Comment: @NoahL Date/time doesn't work in other smartphone either. Also it can be a matter of technical tolerances.

Comment: Hmmm... that's right